# Unexpected value of array in nested loop

Tags: javascript

while practicing with loops I receive kind of weird to me result.

```
let a = [];
let b = [];

for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
  for (let j=0; j<2;j++){
      a.push(0);

  }
  b.push(a);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
//values of arrays after first iteration of outside loop
[ 0, 0 ]
[ [ 0, 0 ] ]
//values of arrays after second...
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

I wonder why value of array b is not equal to `[ [0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] ]`?

Comment: You never make a copy of `a`, so the same array is pushed onto `b` each time through the outer loop.

Comment: Try -> `b.push([...a]);` to get the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are always using the same `a` array.

At the start of the second iteration `a` is `[0, 0]` and you push 2 extra 0s there.

And b is basically `[a, a]` in the end, so if you keep feeding `a` 0s, it's elements will keep growing.

If you want to create a 2D array you would have to make this little modification:

```
let b = [];

for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
  let a = [];
  for (let j=0; j<2;j++){
      a.push(0);

  }
  b.push(a);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

Moving the creation of `let a` into the outer loop means every time that cycles you will create a new, temporal `a` to be later pushed to `b`.

To get the result you want you need to make a copy of the array a, instead, making it:

```
let a = [];
let b = [];

for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
  for (let j=0; j<2;j++){
      a.push(0);
}
  b.push(a.slice());
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: That's not going to give the result the OP is after.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what he wanted, it will. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In his question he expected b = `[ [0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] ]`  But with this code it's going to be `[[0,0],[0,0]]` instead,.  The OP has accepted your answer so, maybe he does want `[[0,0],[0,0]]`..

Comment: Oh, true, I indeed misunderstood. Gonna edit it right away